# Discord Webhook with XMLHttp Request

Tags: typescript, discord, xmlhttprequest, webhooks

I'm trying to trigger a Discord webhook doing this:

```
if ('1' !== '2') {
          console.log(`This is false!`)        
          sendMessage();
```

The message I am trying to send is:

```
function sendMessage() {
          var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          request.open("POST", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/XYZ");
          request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
          var myEmbed = {
              title: "Test",
              color: 0xFF7100,
              fields: [
                  {
                      name: 'Test',
                      value: 'Test',
                  }, {
                      name: 'Test 2',
                      value: "Test 2",
                  }],
              timestamp: new Date(),
              footer: {
                  text: 'v 1.6.2'
              }
          }
          var params = {
              username: "Test Webhook",
              avatar_url: "",
              color: "#FF7100",
              content: "",
              embeds: [myEmbed],
      
          }
          request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
      }
```

I've tried the sendMessage() in the browser console and it successfully sends the webhook, indicating that sendMessage() is not triggered in my project, the console.log works though.

Could someone explain where I made an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by moving to axios:

```
const webhook= 'https://ptb.discord.com/api/webhooks/XYZ';

const axios = require("axios");

function sendWebhook() {
  const request = {
    "content" : `Any Text`, //This will be the regular message above the embed
    "username": "New User",
    "avatar_url": "",
    "embeds": [{
      "color": 0xFF700 ,
      "timestamp": new Date(),
      "author": {
        "name": "",
        "icon_url": "",
      },
      "title": "Any Title",
      "fields": [{
        
        "name": "Field 1",
        "value": "Field 1 value"},
        {        
        "name": "Field 2",
        "value": "Field 2 value"},
        {        
          "name": "Field 3",
          "value": "Field 2 value"},                          
    ],
      "url": "", //This will set an URL for the title
    }],
  };

    return axios.post(webhook, request)
      
}
```

Maybe this will help someone out ♥

Edit: Trigger stayed identical btw